# Remove and Insert in table , Removing previous data using Entity frame work in asp.net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When trying to insert "FromCompany" data to "ToCompany" after saveChanges(); it deleted "FromCompany" data.

I am trying to delete old data , and copy the data from another company to mycompany, but it deleting the data from that comapny after saving it in my company.

This is the example code:

```
foreach (var data in ctx.AllData.Where(a => a.CompanyId == toCompanyId).Select(a => a).ToList())
{
    ctx.AllData.Remove(data);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();

var alldata = ctx.AllData.Where(a => a.CompanyId == fromCompanyId ).Select(a => a).ToList();
foreach (var data in alldata)
{
    var model = new AllData();
    data.CompanyId = toCompanyId;

    model.CompanyId = data.CompanyId;
    model.CategoryId = data.CategoryId;
    model.OtherFields = data.OtherFields;
    
    ctx.AllData.Add(model);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: i am tryingn to delete old data , and copy the data from another company to mycompany, but it deleting the data from that comapny after saving it in my company

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what do you want, and why the code you posted actually doesn't fit your requirements. Please try to explain better to let the community help you.

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori ,I deleted old record from table1 of company A  using company id , After that I get retirve data of Company B from table1 using companyId and in loop inserting the retirved data as Company A data by changing its company ID. but after saveChange function Company B data get deleted from the table i dont know how it happens , hope u get my point

Comment: So the problem is you got all companies with `fromCompanyId` deleted?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori yes exaclty , and this is not going to be happen like this, why this happening I am not able to figure it out

Comment: @abdulkadirsabir the code has a lot of quirks (`.Select(a=>a)` is meaningless) and dangerous patterns (calling `SaveChanges()` in the middle means that any mistake will result in half-saved data). You probably *shouldn't* be using an ORM at all though. Your code is trying to perform batch updates, not work with objects. A single `DELETE AllData Where CompanyID=@to` is *far* better than executing 100 individual DELETEs. The other operations are a *single* `UPDATE .. FROM` and a *single* `INSERT .. FROM`

Comment: As for why the "wrong" company seems to be deleted - did you swap the IDs perhaps? Or pass the same value to both `fromCompany` and `toCompany` ? The line `data.CompanyId = toCompanyId;` will *UPDATE* all `from` company values to `to`. Perhaps you mistook that for an actual deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `foreach` you are changing the `data.CompanyId`. Then calling `ctx.SaveChanges` you are changing all companies with `fromCompanyId`. Try to remove that line, like this:

```
foreach (var data in ctx.AllData.Where(a => a.CompanyId == toCompanyId).Select(a => a).ToList())
{
    ctx.AllData.Remove(data);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();

var alldata = ctx.AllData.Where(a => a.CompanyId == fromCompanyId ).Select(a => a).ToList();
foreach (var data in alldata)
{
    var model = new AllData();

    model.CompanyId = toCompanyId;
    model.CategoryId = data.CategoryId;
    model.OtherFields = data.OtherFields;
    
    ctx.AllData.Add(model);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

While you are calling `ctx.SaveChanges` you are saving all changes were performed in all context's data.